# Heading Component change text color based on the background in React / Gatsby / Styled-components

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, styled-components

Hey folks I hope I can get some help.

I have a Heading Component, the text color I am taking from ThemeProvider from the folder theme that I have is assigned to blue...

```
const Title = styled.h1`
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.15;
  color: ${props => props.theme.colors.main}; <-BLUE COLOR->
`
const SubTitle = styled.h2`
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin: 0;
  color: ${props => props.theme.colors.text};
  font-weight: 400;
`

const Heading = ({ title, subtitle }) => {
  return (
    <HeadingWrapper>
      <Title>{title}</Title>
      <SubTitle>{subtitle}</SubTitle>
    </HeadingWrapper>
  )
}
```

The **body** has blue background.

I have 3 sections

- Component with Assigned white background

```
       <Heading
            title="First Section Is OK"
            subtitle="Here is white background on the div from that section and blue text from the component"
          />
```

- Component with NO background assigned

```
       <Heading
            title="This section Title is NOT good cause I have the blue text color"
            subtitle="Here I don't use background color, I have blue color from the body"
          />
```

- And the Same first component with white background assigned.

```
       <Heading
            title="Third Section Is OK"
            subtitle="Here is white background on the div from that section and blue text from the component"
          />
```

I am using the Heading Component in all 3 sections but on the middle section I can't see the color cause is Blue text and Blue background...

How to approach this problem to have kinda dynamic text color based on the background ???

literally I have a brain fart and I can't thing... Hope you can guide me or give me a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding a property to determine style.

`<Heading title="" subtitle="" textColor="blue" bgColor="green"` />`

Then in your Heading component:

```
const Bg = styled.div`
     background-color: {props.BkgColor}
     color: {props.FontColor}
     ...
`


const Heading = ({props}) => {
     render() {
          return (
               <Bg FontColor={ props.textColor } BkgColor={ props.bgColor }>
                    ...
               </Bg>
          )
     }
}
```